# CSS grid and links

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid, inside which is four divs. The four divs are also `display: grid`. Inside each of the four divs is a link. One of the links contains text that goes on to an extra line. This makes all the divs in the grid taller. But link `hover` on the shorter links does not stretch to the bottom of the div. How do I get the links to stretch the full height of the div? So that the full height is clickable and background colour changes?

```css
.block-intro {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 3.6rem;
}

.button {
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    line-height: 2.8rem;
    text-align: center;
    border:  1px solid;
    }

.button a:link { display: block; color: black; padding: 2.1rem; }
.button a:visited { display: block; color: black; padding: 2.1rem; }
.button a:hover { display: block; color: black; padding: 2.1rem; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
.button a:active { display: block; color: black; padding: 2.1rem; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
```

```html
<div class="block-intro">
    <div class="button">
        <a href="case-studies.php">One line link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="case-studies.php">One line link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="case-studies.php">Two lines<br>longer link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="case-studies.php">One line link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `flex`, see code snippet:

```css
.block-intro {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 3.6rem;
}

.button {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    line-height: 2.8rem;
    text-align: center;
    border:  1px solid;
}

.button a {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: black;
    padding: 2.1rem;
}

.button a:hover, .button a:active { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
```

```html
<div class="block-intro">
    <div class="button">
        <a href="case-studies.php">1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="case-studies.php">One line link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="case-studies.php">Two lines<br>longer link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <a href="case-studies.php">One line link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But now the link (and background color) doesn't extend to the full width of the div

Comment: @user2991837 I've updated the code snippet

Comment: Fab. Thank you. It also seems to work with flex direction and align items removed from the button css.

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a `height: 100%` and it should work. On the example i also added a background color so you can see better the link element

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block-intro {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 3.6rem;
}

.button {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  line-height: 2.8rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.button a:link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: black;
  padding: 2.1rem;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100%;
}

.button a:visited {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 2.1rem;
}

.button a:hover {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 2.1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.button a:active {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 2.1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="block-intro">
  <div class="button">
    <a href="case-studies.php">One line link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <a href="case-studies.php">One line link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <a href="case-studies.php">Two lines<br>longer link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <a href="case-studies.php">One line link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this answer, you lose the vertical centering of the text

Comment: I've quickly copied this over to my code and the link is now taller than the div. It appears to have a height of 100% + padding top + padding bottom

Comment: @user2991837 you are missing the `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` at the top of the css example